# Fill the inside of a hollow font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, adobe-after-effects

If i have a font that has a hollow inside, how can I fill the inside with color? I've tried using an inside stroke but that only strokes inside the lines, not the character. I can't use masks because the text needs to be dynamic.

I'm using After Effects, but if someone knows how to do this in photoshop (other than the fill bucket), it might translate over..

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot fill the font without expanding the font in a program like Illustrator and using the live paint tool to fill the type but then you would not be able to change the letters.

Other options would be to edit the font itself and save it as a new font entirely or find a new font.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this in Illustrator. Create your text, go to the Type menu, and select Create Outlines. You won't be able to edit the type as text any more, but you'll be able to manipulate the letterforms so you can fill the shapes with your desired content.

edit: After outlining the text, I would export it as a transparent image, and then import it to After Effects as an image asset. Hopefully this has answered your question.

Comment: Hmm.. That's sorta an option if worse comes to worser. But I really need it to stay editable, I need to make a countdown using this font.

Answer (score 2):

If worse comes to worst, cheat!

1. Put a blank layer below it,
2. Paint on it with the same color as the outline, remain on the inside of the letters
3. You can make the painting inside easier by Ctrl-Click on the type layer then when the selection is made, press Shift-Ctrl-I to invert the selection. Now the blank areas in the type will be selected, along with the area outside the type. Remain inside the type and paint away (on the blank layer below the text.)

The result will be "filled type" but the type can still be edited. I realize you will have to go back and tweak the painted layer, but ...

Addendum: A couple of images to show the point

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You will need a program like Paint Shop Pro or GIMP with layering and transparent background options.

Create a new image with trans background, or add in later if using existing image.  Apply letters, then duplicate layer for ease of redoing. Select by color on font, then edit to invert selection. Then outside of the font using select tool, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then left mouse click. You should be ready to fill or on tool options, there might be an option near the opacity of the tool, i.e., normal, burn, addition etc. Pick behind if you're steady handed.